# To read the output of a command in a shell script

Tags: shell, scripting

I am running a unix command say ftp to a remote machine through a shell script.I have to pass the userid and password through the script accordingly.How can i do that?

Comment: Looks like you expected an answer to a totally different question than you asked. Lucky SO doesn't let you retract an upvote after a day.

Comment: Looks like your actual issue is supplying username/password from script to ftp. Your question does not say anything about that, edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to supply username/passwords from scripts would be to use 'expect' scripting.

Here is a small example : http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/auto-ssh-login-expect-script-624047/
. It shows using expect to provide password for ssh, ftp should be very similar.

Comment: Could you please explain how to write the expect script for this or provide any useful links?

Comment: What? What does this answer have to do with getting the output of a Unix command in a shell script?

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I see the comment on the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to get the result that the command (say, ftp) wrote to the terminal as a value inside the script?

Use backticks. For example:

```
x=`ftp ...`
```

will run the `ftp` command, and take the text of its stdout and store it in the variable `x`.

Comment: Note that, in bash and other bourne-type shells, it's a syntax error to have spaces around the '='

Comment: Good call. I vaguely knew this but wasn't sure.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect the ftp command inside your shell script

```
ftp .....   > ftp.log
```

Comment: i wanted to ftp to remote machine. Once i give the ftp command it will prompt for the user name and then password.I have to read that from the console and give the username and password accordingly through the script.

Comment: @Ammu, that's not what your question says. Please edit your question to give us your requirements.